# Google App Engine + MongoDB (w/ SSL Certificate)

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, ssl-certificate

I'm in the final stages of launching a website complete w/ a few data visualization apps and user authentication capabilities.  User data is stored in MongoDB on an external server (GCP instance that we manage), and SSL authentication is required.  The problem I'm running into is the following:

In order to connect to MongoDB (create/authenticate/update user information) the path to the ssl certificate is required ("ssl_ca_certs" argument w/in the MongoDB URI).  On a GCP instance (or locally) this is no big deal... just type in the absolute path of the SSL certificate and we're connected, however Google App Engine doesn't appear to have any readable/writable local filesystem, which makes me wonder if using the ssl_ca_certs argument is even possible.

Has anyone had any experience connecting to MongoDB from GAE using an SSL certificate?  If so, what was the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need a readable/writable file system to work with GAE.

You can use GCS (Google Cloud Storage) to write and read your files from GAE (Standard {1} and Flexible {2}).

Maybe another good solution is using environment variables inside your app.yaml
{3},{4}.

{1}: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage

{2}: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage

{3}: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref

{4}: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables