# How can you provide client SSL certificates to Google App Engine applications to access SSL enforced SQL Cloud instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App Engine application (node) connecting to a Google SQL Cloud DB.  Everything works fine.

We want to force SSL connections so anyone accessing the DB requires certs.  Even though GAE connections to SQL cloud are already encrypted, enforcing SSL connections seems to also force GAE applications to have the certs as well.

This is the configuration page I'm talking about:

[image: Force SSL]

The problem is that GAE doesn't have any persistent local file system and as such I don't have an obvious place to store the certs.

...so what is the recommended approach to providing GAE applications with SSL certs for the purpose of connecting to a SQL Cloud instance?  I can put the cert in Google secret manager, but that's inconvenient for a number of reasons.

How are other people addressing this problem?

(I know this is similar to [Google App Engine + MongoDB (w/ SSL Certificate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976851/google-app-engine-mongodb-w-ssl-certificate), but I was hoping that better options would have been provided in the years since that question was asked or that the fact that I was only inside the GCP ecosystem would provide a better option for me.)

Comment: Do you mean your App Engine can't connect to Cloud SQL when Allow only SSL Connection is enabled? May I also know some reasons why using Google secret manager is inconvenient?

Comment: @JohnMichaelGelilio yes - we want to enforce SSL for external connections but it enforces it for internal connections as well, which are already encrypted. I have too many problems with secret manager to fit here but primarily it doesn’t expose secrets as ENV variables so you have to put proprietary code in the app to access them, which means if you want to run it elsewhere you have to handle it as a special case. Also most apps (and staff) expect certs to be managed in files so having them as a string in the console for just a few apps is a pain.